# Find all possible paths in a Matrix

Tags: matrices, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

I'm looking for algorithms to find all paths in a 4 x 4 matrix.
The rules are as follows

- You can move in any direction (up, down, left, right, and diagonally)
- The next square in the path must be a neighbour to the current square
- Each square can only be used once
- Each square in the path must be in the bounds of the matrix
- No squares are restricted
- Start squares don't matter
- End squares don't matter

Here is an example of a valid path

> \begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|}
>  \hline
>           &   6 &   &   8 \\ \hline
>           5&    &   7&   9 \\ \hline
>           3&   4&   0&    \\ \hline
>           2&   1 &   &   \\ \hline
> \end{array}

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of paths?  Are you trying to enumerate each path?  Are any squares restricted?  Is this homework?  Do the start and end squares matter?  Is this homework?

Comment: @DanielV No this is not homework. I'm working on a creating a coding kata to help people think about and improve the performance of their code. This is going to be used in a word game like Boggle and I want to find all possible words / paths. The solution I have now runs fast for paths of length 6 (about .5 of a second) but takes 36 minutes when getting paths of length 7. The start and end squares don't matter as I was thinking of starting from each square in turn to get all paths from each square.

Comment: @DanielV also as long as square is within the bounds of the matrix it can be in the path, I have updated the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Given a path of length $6$, there are at most $7$ paths of length $7$ that start with it.  It seems strange that the increase in time is so large-just find the squares you can extend a path of length $6$ into, then check if that square has been used.

Comment: Also load your dictionary into a trie and filter while you enumerate paths instead of after.

Comment: @RossMillikan how did you calculate the number of paths? That would be very useful for me to know.

Comment: It might be better to ask this question on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) — along with your code, of course.

Comment: @GarethRees I was looking for some algorithms, as I want to mathematical prove the results I get back from my code in my tests. Also programmers don't always keep up to date algorithms so I though here would be a better place to ask.

Comment: As Ross Millikan points out above, it shouldn't take more than 7 times as long to enumerate the length-7 paths as it does to enumerate the length-6 paths. So it seems more likely that you have made a mistake in your implementation than that you are not using the most up-to-date algorithm.

Comment: Each number borders on (at most) eight others.  The ones on the sides and in the corners even less.  You came from somewhere, so cannot go back there.  That leaves at most only seven possible extensions.

Comment: @RossMillikan I thought it was my code that was running slow, however it turns out it is my tests that are running slow. I'm really just looking for help of the maths. Is there a formula to calculate the number of paths? I would like to verify my results with a mathematical proof if possible. For example starting from a corner for a word with 13 characters long I have calculated 228,016 permutations (unique paths)

Comment: @TheLukeMcCarthy I am busy trying to resolve this for exactly the same reason (wanting to write a Boggle solver). Did you get an answer to your question or maybe a hint as to what algorithm one can use?

Comment: @mydoghasworms sorry I didn't get an answer. Perhaps a modified Dijkstra algorithm or a modified A* could work. It's an interesting problem

Comment: @TheLukeMcCarthy I managed to solve the problem (always more satisfying when you figure it out yourself) but I am sure there are probably more effective ways of doing it than what I am doing. I thought of posting it here but it's probably more of a programming-related answer and I'm not sure I can post it on the Math SE. I might post it on Code Review as suggested by Gareth Rees. Did you by any chance post this question there too?

Comment: @mydoghasworms No, I didn't post on Code Review. When you post on Code Review Add a link here so I can see your answer, I'm interested to see what you came up with :D

Comment: @TheLukeMcCarthy I am cleaning up my code to post on Code Review, but in the meantime I wrote the process as an answer here. Will add the link to Code Review once I have posted there.

Comment: @TheLukeMcCarthy My code solution is here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/203292/22855

Comment: @TheLukeMcCarthy Using the advice given on Code Review, here is a much more efficient solution: https://gist.github.com/mydoghasworms/e31a723c114f760942aed11bb0fe3d95

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** - after writing this answer, I realised that I had forgotten that the question was not specifically about Boggle, but in the comments it turned out that the OP and I were talking about Boggle specifically.

**EDIT 2** - I have posted a code solution of this in Ruby on Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/203292/22855

I figured out an algorithm on my own, because it was a lot of fun.

Not being well-versed in algorithms, I would love to know if this algorithm has a name. (Let me know in the comments or edit this answer if you know it, please).

(Note that we have a list of valid words - a dictionary - from which to look up chains of letters).

- Start at a given position on the board
- Put the position on a stack. The stack of positions represents a chain of letters (every position on the board has a letter, remember)
- Once the stack has two or more positions, check whether there are any words starting with those letters. If there are none, pop the stack and return (i.e. abandon the current search path - there is no point going down it further if it won't result in a valid word)
- Once the stack has three or more positions, check the letters (from the positions in the stack) against the dictionary and, if the word exists, add it to a set of words collected.
- Cycle through all the possible next positions in turn (N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW)
- If the next position is out of bounds (off the board) or is already somewhere in the stack, skip that position
- For a valid next position, the routine calls itself (i.e. starts at second point above) with the new position
- Before ending and returning to the previous call, the position is popped off the stack

The whole process is repeated for every position on the board as a starting position, but during processing, paths are aborted, as mentioned, to avoid looking through *every* possible path for a word that doesn't exist.

Also, in my implementation, my input board has "Q" as a single letter, but I have special handling for "Qu" by pushing a "U" after the "Q" on to the stack and checking to pop a "Q" in addition. ("Qu" counts as two letters in Boggle, but takes up a single side of a cube). That's just specific to my implementation, but it could probably be handled in other ways.